# In ground dog composters, are they effective?

Tags: compost, dog, yard

Looking on the internet, I see a lot of plans for an underground dog waste composting systems. They basically all consist of a well drained barrel like container, buried underground, with a small access pipe to the surface. You throw the waste in there, and it breaks down and oozes into the subsoil.

Has anyone ever tried something like this, and did it work well for you?

I live in the city, with a small lot, and have 2 medium-large sized dogs, so they produce quite a lot of waste. I'm not really interested in using any of the compost for gardening at this time, instead I'm just more interested in having an easier method to dispose of it rather than having to bag it up and deal with it that way.

Comment: This question was already asked here and ended up being moved to [sustainability.se] since it wasn't directly about producing compost for gardening: http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/567/1196

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about gardening and landscaping as defined in the [Help Center](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). To bring the question back within scope, you can edit the question to include how this applies to gardening.

Comment: You could also probably ask it on [Pets.SE](http://pets.stackexchange.com/) without too much rewording, if the answers from Sustainablility.SE don't answer your question.